# Understanding conditional expectation $E(X; A)=E(X \mathbf 1_A)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-expectation

From Rick Durret-Essentials of stochastic process, I saw this notation $E(Y;A)=E(Y\mathbf{1}_A)$, and from other text, I also see the definition of $E(Y\mathbf{1}_A)=\int_A Yd\mathbb{P}$. Now, I am trying to bridge this formula with introductory level understanding, I still have no intuition about what exactly $E(Y\mathbf{1}_A)$ is, and Rick comments *"Note that multiplying $Y$ by $\mathbf{1}_A$ sets the product $= 0$ on $A^C$ and leaves the values on $A$ unchanged"*

Can anyone elaborate Rick's comment a bit?

I was thinking about $$E(Y\mathbf{1}_A)=\sum y\mathbf{1}_A\mathbb{P}(\text{not sure what should I write here})+\sum y\mathbf{1}_{A^c}\mathbb{P}(\text{not sure what should I write here})$$

The second term is $0$

Is this interpretation correct? and what should I write in $\mathbb{P}(\cdot)$?

Comment: Just to check, you _are_ familiar with the definition of the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) denoted by $\mathbf 1_A$, right? (Mainly, that $\mathbf 1_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $\mathbf 1_A(x) = 0$ otherwise.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen What is the codomain of the indicator function?

Comment: @Filippo $\{0,1\}$, but I still do not see anything. Especially it said leaves the values on $A$ unchanged

Comment: @LJNG I agree that $\{0,1\}$ is the image, but is it also the preferred codomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $A\subset\Omega,~ \mathbb E(X; A):= \int_A X~\mathrm dP. $ Now $$\mathbf 1_A :=\begin{cases}1,~\omega\in A\\ 0,~\omega\in \Omega\setminus A\end{cases}.$$ Therefore $$Y\mathbf 1_A =\begin{cases}Y,~\omega\in A\\ 0,~\omega\in \Omega\setminus A\end{cases}.$$ The rest follows.